# Technical problem between fourier/fouriernc and mathalpha packages

Tags: symbols, packages, mathcal, mathbb

I am trying to use the `fourier`/`fouriernc` math packages in LaTeX all while defining the `\mathbb`, `\mathcal`, `\mathscr` and `\mathfrak` commands at will. I have tried doing this with the `mathalpha` package, but I ran into a problem.

I am trying to make my document look like this all while keeping the `fourier`/`fouriernc` package:
[image: Result2]

Here is the code I put in on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[arrowdel]{physics}
\usepackage[bb=ams, cal=cm, scr=boondox, frak=euler]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{fourier}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathbb{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathcal{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathscr{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathfrak{ABCDEFG}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And here is the result I got instead of the desired output:
[image: Result]

The result is exactly the same with both `fourier` and `fouriernc` packages. I suspect that the `fourier`/`fouriernc` packages have overwritten the `mathalpha` commands for `\mathbb` and `\mathcal`. My question is: How can I avoid this completely when using the packages? If it is impossible, what alternatives can I use to define math alphabets at will while using the `fourier`/`fouriernc` packages? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you load `mathalpha` *after* loading `fourier`, `mathalpha` will redefine the `\mathcal`, `\mathscr` and `\mathfrak` commands according to your will. `mathalpha` will also redefine `\mathbb`, but `fourier` also redefines the `\mathbb` command at the beginning of the document (it took me a while to figure it out). Hence, the `\mathbb` command has to be redefined after the beginning of the document, for example with `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[bb=ams, cal=cm, scr=boondox, frak=euler]{mathalpha}
\let\amsmathbb\mathbb
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\mathbb\relax
    \newcommand{\mathbb}[1]{\amsmathbb{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathbb{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathcal{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathscr{ABCDEFG}$
    \item[\textbullet] $\mathfrak{ABCDEFG}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have just tried doing this. And it worked. Many thanks for you help! :D